# Crashlytics not reporting, Result was 202

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics-android

I've checked for possible duplicate and found one, but having implemented his solution and not finding any luck, thought I'd ask the experts.

Crashlytics has been setup on my app properly. But it isn't reporting the errors in my dashboard. I've attached a picture from my terminal. The crash is being handled and an attempt is made to send it to the dashboard.

Perhaps there is a delay from the time I setup crashlytics for the first time? It has been up and running for at least 30 minutes. And I've also downloaded the google-services-json file again after setting it up.

Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine. There was just a delay in the reporting. The crashes have started showing up now, but they aren't as instant as I thought they would be. Much more detailed than Google Developers crash report though.